# MySQL is not working after Windows 8.1 update

Tags: mysql, windows-8.1, wampserver

I have **Wamp Server 2.5** installed and it was working fine until my **Windows 8.1 update**. After the update the Wamp Server has became very slow. I have searched for the solution the whole night and tried every possible solution but no joys :( I re-install **wamp, disable IPv6, removed cache**, etc. I tried to install **Xampp Server** then but it has the same issue. I came to know that the issue is with MySQL. Whenever I access my project which requires connection with database it doesn't respond but whenever I access any static page it works normally. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

1. localhost may be needed to replace with 127.0.0.1 in your program
2. 'Listen 80' need to replace with 'Listen 0.0.0.0:80' in httpd.conf